# how to get text from span in the below code

Tags: selenium, checkbox, dropdown

[image: regiondropdown][image: Unable to save][image: UI/web Page]I want to get text from all the check boxes given in a drop down box in order to compare those values with db. Please help me. I am able to count the size by options.size(), but unable to get the text/strings to compare with each string in db.

```
//Click on Select Box
Thread.sleep(500);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DivZone']/div/button")).click();
Thread.sleep(500);
List<WebElement> options =    
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@name, 
'multiselect_ddlZone')]"));
//List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".ui-
corner-all.ui-state-hover>span"));
List<String> all_elements_text=new ArrayList<>();
if(region!=null)
{
for(int i=1; i<options.size(); i++)
{
all_elements_text.add(options.get(i).getText());
System.out.println(options.get(i).getText());
boolean isThere = false;
for (int j = 0; j < region.size(); j++) 
{
if 
(options.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(region.get(j))) {
// Code to display warning
isThere = true;
}
}
if(isThere)
System.out.println(options.get(i).getText()+" is matched 
with Database data");
else
System.out.println(options.get(i).getText()+" is not matched 
with Database data");
}
}
```

[image: debug]

Comment: What do you mean unable to get the text/strings?? I'd there any exception or something else???

Comment: No exceptions, the variable is blank, where I am trying to store the text

Comment: Ok try then as `System.out.println(options.get(i).getAttribute("textContent"));` and let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Right now, each "option" is an "input" WebElement, which will not have any text.
You may want to try searching for the list items, then pulling out the span content:

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li label[for*='ddlZone'] span"));
```

Comment: I want text in all the options. Here, in your code how to write it for getting the text? I am not even getting the size of the options used your code for CSS....please see the attached image

Comment: Ah!  My bad.  There are, of course, many other drop down menus in your UI.  I've edited the path to restrict to just the label elements that have "ddlZone" in the "for" attribute.  That should work.  (It's hard to tell if that should be dd1Zone, or ddlZone)

Answer (score 0):

If unfortunately `getText()` doesn't work, you should try using `getAttribute("textContent"‌​)` as below :-

```
System.out.println(options.get(i).getAttribute("textContent"‌));
```

Or try using `getAttribute("innerHTML"‌)` as below :-

```
System.out.println(options.get(i).getAttribute("innerHTML"‌));
```

Comment: @Breaks Software, I am unable to save with above path. please find the screen shot

Comment: Thank you, break software, its working but, the same path is not working for other drop down.This is working for below code

Comment: List<WebElement> zonelist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.ui-multiselect-checkboxes li label[for*='ddlZone'] span"));
    List<String> all_zonelist=new ArrayList<>();
 
    for(int zui=0; zui<zonelist.size(); zui++)
    {
     all_zonelist.add(zonelist.get(zui).getText());

Comment: but, its not working for other drop down, I will attach the screen shot

Comment: I think this is copy paste issue in IDE, try to write it instead of copy paste..:)

Comment: Yes, I have written. Now, I am able to catch the size but not getting the text!

Comment: Are you using `.getAttribute("textContent"‌);` or `.getAttribute("innerHTML"‌)`??

Comment: I was able to get the text using getText(); in previous drop down

Comment: So here if you are not able get the text using `getText();` then try using one of these `.getAttribute("textContent"‌);` or `.getAttribute("innerHTML"‌);`

Comment: Tried but not getting the text:  for(int rui=0; rui<regionlist.size(); rui++)
    {
     allregionlist.add(regionlist.get(rui).getAttribute("textContent"));
  boolean isthere = true;
     for (int rdb=0; rdb<RegionsinDB.length; rdb++)
     {
      
      if (!(regionlist.get(rui).getAttribute("textContent")).equalsIgnoreCase(RegionsinDB[rdb]))
      {
       isthere = false;
          
      }else

Comment: Got everything, thanks to each one of you for your support, I have used .getAttribute(), I had missed to update in all the places. Now I am able to catch the text. Thanks again.

Comment: allregionlist.add(regionlist.get(rui).getAttribute("textContent"));
-------   
(!(regionlist.get(rui).getAttribute("textContent")).equalsIgnoreCase(RegionsinDB[rdb]))
    System.out.println("\nThe Region in the UI-> " +(regionlist.get(rui).getAttribute("textContent"))+ " existing in the MDB" );
   else
    System.out.println("\nThe Region in the UI-> " +(regionlist.get(rui).getAttribute("textContent"))+ " not existing in the MDB");

Comment: Ok if it helped [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as well..:)

Answer (score 0):

Gave it a try on "www.tripadvisor.in", and able to make it (Used 'break' statement just to limit the loop in the example). Below is the code I tried on

```
public class SelectList {
WebDriver driver;

By currencyDrop = By.xpath(".//*[@id='CURRENCYPOP']/span");
By currency = By.xpath(".//*[@id='GLOBAL_CURRENCY_PICKER']/ul/li");

@Test 
public void f() throws InterruptedException { 

driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.in/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(currencyDrop).click();

//Below is the list of options present in dropdown(per DB)
 String[] expList = {"INR ₹ Indian Rupees", 
                     "USD US$ U.S. Dollars", 
                     "EUR € Euros"};

List <WebElement>countryList = driver.findElements(currency);

int i =0;

for(WebElement curr:countryList){
    if (i>2){
        break;
    }
    if (curr.getText().equals(expList[i])){
        System.out.println("ActCurrency" + curr.getText());
        System.out.println("ExpCurrency" + expList[i]);
i++;
    }
}
}
}
```